# How to tell whether a database login is disabled without using the GUI in a select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have been searching for an answer for the last 30 minutes on google, but haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer.

I am able to retrieve a list of db logins from the syslogins table, but it doesn't contain a field to indicate whether the login is disabled. I need to use this in a select query. Can anyone enlighten me?

Note that this applies to sql server 2000.

Comment: If the login is not a windows login name then there is really no way of turning that off in SQL Server 2000. You could look at the sysadmin, securityadmin, serveradmin, setupadmin, processadmin, diskadmin, dbcreator and bulkadmin fields and if they are all zero then consider it disabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select name, hasaccess
from sys.syslogins
```

I believe the field `hasaccess` is what you are looking for.  As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx), `hasaccess` is `1` if the login has access to the instance, and `0` if not.

Comment: Thanks Shark. For some reason, I had the field name 'is_disabled' stuck in my brain. I just ran the select on my server and checked the results against the GUI and it's a match.

Comment: @JamesJiao Glad to help!  `is_disabled` is a field in the `sys.server_principals` catalog view in SQL Server 2005 and up.  So it's understandable that was stuck in your brain!

Answer (score 5):

Reducing the join:

select name, is_disabled  from sys.sql_logins
where is_disabled=1
order by 1

Comment: This will not show the status of those which have a login via an AD account.

Answer (score 2):

use sys.sql_logins for checking enable/disable status of login.
example

```
select * from syslogins sl
join 
sys.sql_logins sql
 on sl.sid=sql.sid
where is_disabled=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT is_disabled,*
    FROM sys.sql_logins
```

Comment: This only shows sql logins and not active directory logins.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is incorrect as it wont provide useful information.If the account is Disabled, still the column `hasaccess` can be `1`.

The closest correct one is:

```
select name,is_disabled,* from sys.sql_logins where name = '' , if its an SQL account.
```